# How to resolve com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast... Java Spark

Tags: java, mongodb, hive, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to Java Spark, and have been looking for solutions for couple of days.

I am working on loading MongoDB data into hive table, however, I found some error while saveAsTable that occurs this error

```
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)) (value: BsonString{value='54d3e8aeda556106feba7fa2'})
```

I've tried increase the sampleSize, different mongo-spark-connector versions, ... but non of working solutions.

I can't figure out what is the root cause and what are the gaps in between that needs to be done?

The most confusing part is I have similar sets of data using the same flow without issue.

the mongodb data schema is like nested struct and array

```
root
 |-- sample: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- parent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- expanded: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- distance: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- keys: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- parent_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
```

sample data

```
    "sample": {
      "expanded": [
        {
          "distance": 0,
          "type": "domain",
          "id": "54d3e17b5cf737074d4065b0",
          "parent_id": [
            "54d3e1775cf737074d406599"
          ],
          "name": "level2"
        },
        {
          "distance": 1,
          "type": "domain",
          "id": "54d3e1775cf737074d406599",
          "name": "level1"
        }
      ],
      "id": [
        "54d3e17b5cf737074d4065b0"
      ]
    }
```

sample code

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // spark session read mongodb
    SparkSession mongo_spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
            .config("mongo_spark.master", "local")
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db.test_collection")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();

    // Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(mongo_spark.sparkContext());

    // Load data and infer schema, disregard toDF() name as it returns Dataset
    Dataset<Row> implicitDS = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
    implicitDS.printSchema();
    implicitDS.show();

    // createOrReplaceTempView to see if the data being read
    // implicitDS.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table");
    // implicitDS.printSchema();
    // implicitDS.show();

    // saveAsTable
    implicitDS.write().saveAsTable("my_table");
    mongo_spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table limit 1").show();

    mongo_spark.stop();
}
```

If anyone have some thoughts I would be very much appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample data please?

Comment: This looks like an object id is not being correctly converted from a string

Comment: I updated with a sample data, pretty much the schema can tell. if objectid not being correctly converted from a string what can I do? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I increase the sample size properly, this problem doesn't exist anymore.

[How to config Java Spark sparksession samplesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004914/how-to-config-java-spark-sparksession-samplesize)

Comment: Have the same issue and increasing of sampleSize didn't help me

Comment: Even for me, increasing the sample size is not helping for me.
I have added the same concern as a questions.

Comment: increasing sample size will make spark scan more rows and make better guess in comingup with schema. If you have 1 bad row while all other 10M rows comply to a schema, then you will get into the issue till the bad row is removed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and **sampleSize** partially fixes this problem, but doesn't solve it if you have a lot of data.

Here is the solution how you can fix this. Use this approach together with increased **sampleSize** (in my case it's 100000):

```
def fix_schema(schema: StructType) -> StructType:
    """Fix spark schema due to inconsistent MongoDB schema collection.

    It fixes such issues like:
        Cannot cast STRING into a NullType
        Cannot cast STRING into a StructType

    :param schema: a source schema taken from a Spark DataFrame to be fixed
    """
    if isinstance(schema, StructType):
        return StructType([fix_schema(field) for field in schema.fields])
    if isinstance(schema, ArrayType):
        return ArrayType(fix_schema(schema.elementType))
    if isinstance(schema, StructField) and is_struct_oid_obj(schema):
        return StructField(name=schema.name, dataType=StringType(), nullable=schema.nullable)
    elif isinstance(schema, StructField):
        return StructField(schema.name, fix_schema(schema.dataType), schema.nullable)
    if isinstance(schema, NullType):
        return StringType()
    return schema


def is_struct_oid_obj(struct_field: StructField) -> bool:
    """
    Checks that our schema has StructType field with single oid name inside

    :param struct_field: a StructField from Spark schema
    :return bool
    """
    return (isinstance(struct_field.dataType, StructType)
            and len(struct_field.dataType.fields) == 1
            and struct_field.dataType.fields[0].name == "oid")
```