# MongoDb - Spark - Cannot cast STRING into a NullType (value: BsonString{value='4492148'})

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract Data from MongoDb to my DF. Using Java Spark

Below is the sample Code :-

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .setMaster("local")
        .set("spark.app.id", "MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
        .set("sampleSize", args[2])
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.numberOfPartitions", "64")

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf)

DataFrame df = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();

System.out.println("DF Count - " + df.count());        
df.printSchema();
```

There are 2 tables, and 1 Table i am able to fetch data without any issues, but for another table i get the following issue -

```
20/07/15 14:17:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4)
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a NullType (value: BsonString{value='4492148'})
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:80)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:38)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.documentToRow(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.castToStructType(MapFunctions.scala:109)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:75)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:38)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.documentToRow(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.castToStructType(MapFunctions.scala:109)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:75)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:38)
```

From Google the only solution i see is to increase the sample size and still it is not working.

[Cast failing From Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965429/how-to-resolve-com-mongodb-spark-exceptions-mongotypeconversionexception-cannot)
[Increase Sample Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004914/how-to-config-java-spark-sparksession-samplesize)

The second table volume is bit higher, and i have tried a higher sample size but still it fails.

Any other suggestion or ideas to solve this will be useful.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm in the same issue when I found your post.

Answer (score 1):

I am using glue and was facing the same issue while loading the data from documentDB(Mongo API).
I made below changes while reading to resolve this error.

```
df=spark.read.format("mongo").option("ssl.domain_match","false").option("replaceDocument" , "false").option("database","mydatabase").option("collection", "mycollection").option("uri","myurl").load(schema=new_schema, inferSchema=False)
```

Please note: I have tried passing inferSchema and schema parameters using ".option()" as well but that did not work. When I passed the same parameters in "load()" as given in sample code, it worked.

Comment: Hey , sorry , saw this comment in here now. I created my schema as Json properties and then added those columns for null as false and columns which are mandatory for null is true. that solved my issue.